# Why can't Entity Framework translate this linq query? "The LINQ expression could not be translated."

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Why can't this query be translated? Just with one "First()" it works, with two it doesn't:

Exception:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet (whole query here) could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync*

```cs
await RecipesComparatorContext.ItemRecipesComparisonResults
    .Where(compResult => (compResult.IdItemRecipeFromNavigation // From or two the same, both exist
                                                   .ItemRecipesTreeIdItemRecipeParentNavigations.First() 
                                                   .ItemRecipesTreesRoots.First()
                                                   .IdItemRecipeRootNavigation
                                                   .MRPublishedVersions.First().PlantName == plantName)
                                                   
                            )
            )
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(result => result.SetProperty(r => r.InvalidState, true));
```

If it's solved with the ToListAsync(), where should I put it?

The Model is as follow:

```
public partial class ItemRecipesComparisonResult
{
    public int IdItemRecipesComparisonResult { get; set; }
    public int IdItemRecipeFrom { get; set; }
    public int IdItemRecipeTo { get; set; }
    public bool InvalidState { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemRecipe IdItemRecipeFromNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemRecipe IdItemRecipeToNavigation { get; set; }
}


public partial class ItemRecipe
{
    public ItemRecipe()
    {
        ItemRecipesTreeIdItemRecipeChildNavigations = new HashSet<ItemRecipesTree>();
        ItemRecipesTreeIdItemRecipeParentNavigations = new HashSet<ItemRecipesTree>();
        MRPublishedVersions = new HashSet<MRPublishedVersion>();
    }

    public int IdItemRecipe { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<ItemRecipesTree> ItemRecipesTreeIdItemRecipeChildNavigations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemRecipesTree> ItemRecipesTreeIdItemRecipeParentNavigations { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<ItemRecipesTreesRoot> ItemRecipesTreesRoots { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MRPublishedVersion> MRPublishedVersions { get; set; }
}

public partial class ItemRecipesTree
{
    public ItemRecipesTree()
    {
        ItemRecipeInstances = new HashSet<ItemRecipeInstance>();
        ItemRecipesTreesRoots = new HashSet<ItemRecipesTreesRoot>();
    }

    public int IdItemRecipeParent { get; set; }
    public int IdItemRecipeChild { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemRecipe IdItemRecipeChildNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemRecipe IdItemRecipeParentNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemRecipesTreesRoot> ItemRecipesTreesRoots { get; set; }
}


public partial class ItemRecipesTreesRoot
{
    public int IdItemRecipeTreeRoot { get; set; }
    public int IdItemRecipeParent { get; set; }
    public int IdItemRecipeChild { get; set; }
    public int IdItemRecipeRoot { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemRecipesTree IdItemRecipeNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemRecipe IdItemRecipeRootNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class MRPublishedVersion
{
    public int idVersion {get;set;}
    public string PlantName {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Show your model classes and explain why you have used such construction for the query. I think logic is incorrect and probably you need to update state for `compResult` which has t least one `IdItemRecipeChild == 5`, right?

Comment: `ToList()` (and the other methods mentioned) is an eager evaluation; it moves the Linq expression from the server to the client, so that it becomes ordinary Linq instead of Entity Framework Linq.

Comment: I would argue that _"Why"_ is better should be addressed at EF Core github page.

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv, the IdItemRecipeChild == 5, was to simplify the problem, but you are right, as i don't want to get just one record, i may get many, so I change it, see the edit please.

Comment: Do not simplify anything. Query is not translatable by EF Core and for suggesting solution I have to see whole picture.

Comment: It's simplified, but this is what I am running and what is failing.
So basically I want to get all the ItemRecipesComparisonResults
which have any (that's why the First() ItemRecipesTreeIdItemRecipeParentNavigations
which has any (that's why the second First()) ItemRecipeInstances
with IsBeautiful = true

Comment: [This query](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tmuI3g) works for you?

Comment: give me a while please i need to leave now for a while

Comment: Hello, i am back, i just updated the post with the real query and the model!

Comment: By the way, the query you ask me to test, it's not compiling, can you have a look please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite query in the following way, it should be translatable:

```cs
var itemsToUpdate = RecipesComparatorContext.ItemRecipesComparisonResults
    .Where(c => c.IdItemRecipeFromNavigation.ItemRecipesTreeIdItemRecipeParentNavigations 
        .SelectMany(p => p.ItemRecipesTreesRoots)
        .SelectMany(r => r.IdItemRecipeRootNavigation.MRPublishedVersions)
        .Any(v => v.PlantName == plantName)
    );

await itemsToUpdate.ExecuteUpdateAsync(result => result.SetProperty(r => r.InvalidState, true));
```

Comment: Thank you, First() is not the way, but .SelectMany and .Any!